# Input voltage shift of a comparator

Tags: capacitance, comparator, hysteresis, positive-feedback

I am working on an envelope detector circuit. The circuit diagram is as shown here:[image: circuit_diagram]

The output of the envelope detector (RC) is connected to the inverting input of the comparator with hysteresis which has two threshold voltages as shown in the circuit diagram.

When I simulate the circuit I see that the detected envelope is raised by 0.4V (also the lower threshold voltage set by the hysteresis), as shown in this figure:[image: input_voltage_shift] and without connecting the envelope detector to the comparator, the detected envelope is fine: [image: actual_envelope]

What would be the reason for this shift and how can it be avoided?

Note:
Voltage waveforms across the Schottky diodes are as follows:

when envelope detector is connected to comparator: [image: volt_diode_connected]
when the envelope detector is not connected to the comparator: [image: volt_diode_not_connected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What would be the reason for this shift and how can it be avoided?*

Look at the input bias current of this op-amp: -

[image]

It *wants* to push that current from the inputs (to work correctly) and, it will create a voltage error if the input source has any resistance. When the bridge isn't conducting, that input source impedance is the 300 kΩ resistor (R1 in your circuit) so, you might see 1 μA (ish) into the 300 kΩ producing an offset voltage of about 300 mV.

It seems to me that the RC time constant of your envelope detector can be maintained whilst reducing R1 maybe to 3 kΩ and lifting C1 to 5 nF. This would radically reduce the offset but, at what expense (I can't answer that of course).

You should also note that when operating with an input voltage close to the negative rail, the problem is worse. For instance, at higher offset voltages, the bias current drops a lot but, that may make it very inconvenient circuit-wise.

Comment: This works. Thanks, I tried reducing the value of the resistor close to the value which does not have an effect on the rest of circuit

Comment: OK, that's probably the easiest approach.